# start activity without bringing application to foreground

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I'm facing a problem with my android app. In my splashscreen after some verifications the app starts the homeactivity but if the user gets to another app, the homeactivity of my app will still get to the foreground of the device. Is there a way to start the homeactivity without bringing my app to front?
I tried this code but it did not work

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of launching `HomeActivity` instantly just raise a flag and consume it next time your `SplashScreen` is in resumed state. For example you can use `LiveData` to store the flag and observe it:

```
// inside SplashScreen or its ViewModel if you have one
MutableLiveData<Boolean> isVerifiedLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

// inside SplashScreen
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /* ...... add this to onCreate .... */

    isVerifiedLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Boolean isVerified) {
            if(isVerified){
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then to trigger activity change simply modify `isVerifiedLiveData` value:

```
isVerifiedLiveData.setValue(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used the "onResume" and the "onPause" to set the values of the isVerifiedLiveData and all was ok.